# Deleting previous added Component of a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, gameobject

I have this script where it would add the SelectMove script at runtime when a character was touched by the user.

```
public GameObject target;

    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.touchCount > 0 || Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began){
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);

            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin,ray.direction * 20,Color.red);

            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit,Mathf.Infinity)){
                Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject.name);


                target = hit.transform.gameObject; 
                //Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
                selectedPlayer();
            }
        }
    }

    void selectedPlayer(){

                target.AddComponent(Type.GetType("SelectMove"));

    }
```

In the code above, if the user will click Player A, Player A will move using accelerometer. What I need to do is if I click another character, say Player B, I need Player A to stop moving and it is now Player B's time to move. But I seemed not to get what I want. I tried destroying the script by using `Destroy(this)` or by this code:

```
if (target != null)
                {
                    var sphereMesh = target.GetComponent<SelectMove>();
                    Destroy(sphereMesh);
                }
```

But it is still not working.

If I don't destroy the previous added script, if the user clicks for another character, the previous selected player still moves along with the new one.

Is there another way that I could achieve what I needed to do?

Comment: It's better to set it to false, rather than destroy `sphereMesh.enabled = false`

Comment: Destroy should work fine.  **(ONE)** at your code Destroy(sphereMesh); add Debug.Log("i am here");  Determine if "Destroy" is actually being called. Report back to us!

Comment: It's actually working now. I have the same code as stated above, but it works fine now. I don't know what I did, but thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public GameObject target = null;

void Update () 
{
   if(Input.touchCount > 0 || Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
   {
       Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
       Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin,ray.direction * 20,Color.red);
       RaycastHit hit;
       if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit,Mathf.Infinity))
       {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject.name);
            if(this.target != null){
                SelectMove sm = this.target.GetComponent<SelectMove>()
                if(sm != null){ sm.enabled = false; }
            }
            target = hit.transform.gameObject; 
            //Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
            selectedPlayer();
       }
    }
 }

 void selectedPlayer(){
    SelectMove sm = this.target.GetComponent<SelectMove>();
       if(sm == null){
           target.AddComponent<SelectMove>();
       }
       sm.enabled = true;  
 }
```

The code reuses your base, the new part is that you use the previous selected object to disable the SelectMove script (I assume it is the one moving things). Instead of destroying it, it enables/disables so you save that memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Adding and destroying scripts is the convenient method here.
Try this:
1. Add the SelectMove script to all movable players.
2. Add a public property `bool IsMoving = false;` to the SelectMove script and make an if statement to move if IsMoving is true.
3. Change selectedPlayer() method to instead change the target player IsMoving to true, and set the previous one (or simply all other players) to false.

Comment: I'm confused on how to implement step 3.

Comment: Where do you destroy the script, you could change that to `target.IsMoving =false;`